# MongoDB: aggregate $project add field with static value

Tags: mongodb

Can I somehow add custom field with static (not computed) value?

I want to prepare objects before send and I need to remove some fields with internal information and add field with some entity ID.

For example I have collection "test" with objects like this

```
{_id: ObjectId(...), data: {...}}
```

And I need to convert it to

```
{data: {...}, entity_id: 54}
```

So how can I add entity_id: 54 without looping over result in my code?

```
db.test.aggregate({ $project: {_id: 0, data: 1, entity_id: ? } })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Note that $literal was implemented in Mongo 2.6.
So now you can simply write:

```
db.test.aggregate(
   {$project: {_id: 0, data: 1, entity_id: {$literal: 54}}})
```

See [$literal](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#exp._S_literal).

Answer (score 22):

**edit** as of 2.6 the `$literal` expression exists so you don't have to use the workaround now.

Original answer: I know this may sound really dumb, but you can use a "no-op" expression to "compute" what you need.

Example:

```
db.test.aggregate( { $project : {_id:0, data:1, entity_id: {$add: [54]} } } )
```

There was a proposed `$literal` operator for exactly this use case but it hasn't been implemented yet, you can vote for it [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5782).

Comment: Thanks, $literal really can be helpful. Little fix for your example - entity_id: {$add:[54]}

Comment: right - I was thinking of a slightly different example, of course you don't need to add 0 :)