# Select data and create raw value mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I need to add a value that is hardcoded into a mongodb select.  If I were using mysql, this would be easy:

```
SELECT *, 'hardcoded' as hardcoded_value WHERE ...
```

How can I accomplish the equivalent in Mongodb?  I looked at [MongoDB: aggregate $project add field with static value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110822/mongodb-aggregate-project-add-field-with-static-value), however I don't want to aggregate.  I need to find specific records, but then add one hardcoded field into them. My select is:

```
db.collection.find({
    limit:options.limit < 200 ? options.limit : 200, //limit to 200 results
    skip:options.skip,
    sort:options.sort
})
```

I would like to add `paginationResult:1` to every document, so I can keep track of where it was selected.  Why do I need to do this?  I'm using meteor, and meteor requires weird things sometimes for nonstandard use cases because its a newer framework.

FOund:

```
.aggregate([{$match: {_id:'2EJJ2zn7pNnc5v2s6'}},{$project:{_id:1,pagination:{$add:1}}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

The default `find` operation by itself can not do this. You will have to use projection or implement this in your application after receiving the documents.

People who switch from mySQL to MongoDB have to get used to MongoDB being a lot "dumber" than SQL. Many things SQL databases can do themselves needs to be handled by application logic when using MongoDB.

Comment: Ok... Looks like I have to use $project.  Could you give some sample code on how to accomplish what I'm looking for?  In the post I mentioned, I didn't see any sort of find or $match.

Comment: found it! see my post above